# I have js inside xul file and I want to call specific function from the main window

Tags: javascript, dom-events, xul

Now I will try to mention my problem:

I have a function called `playIt()`, inside my Javascript file.

This is the Javascript file:

```
playIt(){
    alert("yes it work!");
}
```

This Javascript code is inside a XUL file.

And I have this source code:

```
<html>
<head>
<title>this is title</title>
</head>
<body>
<div id="clickIt" onclick="javascript:playIt();">
</body>
</html>
```

But the problem is that nothing happens when I click on the div and the function doesn't start.

Comment: That's HTML, not XUL.  XUL doesn't have a 'div' element.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

better way is to attach an event once the content has loaded.

https://developer.mozilla.org/en/Code_snippets/On_page_load

after the line `// do something with the loaded page.`
add your own code

```
doc.getElementById('clickIt').addEventListener('click',playIt,false);
```

Edit:
remove the `javascript:` from the onclick attribute before anything and re-test !!

Comment: you are the best of the best !! Thank you

Comment: but if i have function with parameters, i see this is not work properly with parameters.. what is the right way to do it ?

Comment: you gotta find a workaround for params  
example: if it's your own html then add the params as attributes  
`<div id="clickIt" param1="value1" param2="value2"><div>`  
or: use global variables.

Comment: Thank you i found another solution. i have 2 other question, 1.how can i see my generl.js in runtime ? 2.there is a easy way to implement jquery ? cause i found some tutorial on the internet but they were bad and not understood at all. Thanks.

Comment: 1 - install chromebug for firefox then start firefox with -chromebug in the command line parameters  

2 - i tried but found no good solution !! honestly but i'll notify you if found anything useful

Comment: last one questions, i am trying to make action but this time from iframe and i cannot make it.. ? what can be the problem, of course i check id Thank You

Comment: acessing the iframe is a bit trickier  you gotta go like this
doc.getElementById('iframeid').contentDocument.getElementById('clickIt').addEventListener('click',playIt,false);

Comment: :( i so want to say,, Thank You!!! , but...still the triggert is not working.. do u know why?

Comment: no idea ! but check if doc.getElementById('iframeid').contentDocument.getElementById('clickIt') is returning the elements you want and not generating an error

Comment: i am trying to do that but this is very difficult to make it with chromebug, when i am doing that i get message doc is known

Comment: the best way is to make a breakpoint in the script tab on the line where doc is on scope. and then test on the console. that way doc will be defined and not unknown